# Optaplanner OptaPlannerXmlSerializationException when using benchmark

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, optimization, optaplanner

Hello im new to optaplanner and im trying to use the benchmark functionality in the library so i can test multiple local search algorithme on only one dataset.

But when i launch my benchmark it returns to me this error which is an OptaplannerXmlSerializationException
[image]

This is how i call the benchmark :
[image]

This is my benchmark xml file :
[image]

This is my Entity class :
[image]

This is my Solution class :
[image]

Im stuck here any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The `OptaplannerXmlSerializationException` is defined in `optaplanner-core`, while the `PlannerBenchmarkFactory` comes from `optaplanner-benchmark`. Would you please check the deployment of your application? Is there a chance these classes are loaded by different classloaders?

Comment: +1 looks like tomcat is in the mix and according to the tags Spring too. [This should fix this.](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2341)